# Request body empty (?) after migrating to Endpoints Framework 2.0

Tags: java, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a Java Google Endpoint as follows

```
@ApiMethod(
        name="createShiftlist",
        path="jeugdhuis/{websafeJeugdhuisKey}/shiftlists",
        httpMethod="POST",
        authenticators={FirebaseAuthenticator.class}
        )
public void createShiftlist(User user, @Named("websafeJeugdhuisKey") String websafeJeugdhuisKey, ShiftlistForm shiftlistForm)
        throws UnauthorizedException {

    if (shiftlistForm.getStart() == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(shiftlistForm.getStart() + " " + shiftlistForm.getPartyName() + " " + shiftlistForm.getEnd());

    if (user == null)
      throw new UnauthorizedException("User is not logged in!");

    if (!JukteUserAPI.isJeugdhuisAdmin(user, websafeJeugdhuisKey)) 
      throw new UnauthorizedException("Logged in user is not an admin of the given Jeugdhuis.");

    OfyService.ofy().save().entities(new Shiftlist[] {
      new Shiftlist(
      OfyService.factory().allocateId(Key.create(websafeJeugdhuisKey), Shiftlist.class).getId(), 
      websafeJeugdhuisKey, shiftlistForm.getPartyName(), shiftlistForm.getStart(), shiftlistForm.getEnd()) 
      });
}
```

I use the following .js to call it.

```
var jukteapi = jukteapi || {};
var jukteKey = 'myKey';

function XHRBuilder(appId, apiName, version) {
    this.root = "https://" + appId + ".appspot.com/_ah/api/" + apiName + "/" + version + "/";
    this.params;
    this.method;
    this.endpoint;
    this.authorizationToken;
    this.onsucces;

    this.get = function() {
        this.method = 'GET';
        return this;
    };

    this.post = function() {
        this.method = 'POST';
        return this;
    };

    this.delete = function() {
        this.method = 'DELETE';
        return this;
    };

    this.put = function() {
        this.method = 'PUT';
        return this;
    }

    this.path = function(endpointPath) {
        this.endpoint = endpointPath;
        return this;
    };

    this.authorizationToken = function(token) {
        this.authorizationToken = token;
        return this;
    };

    this.onsucces = function(func) {
        this.onsucces = func;
        return this;
    };

    this.addParam = function(paramName, paramValue) {
        if (this.params === undefined)
            this.params = new FormData();
        this.params.append(paramName, paramValue);
        return this;
    };

    this.send = function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(this.method, this.root + this.endpoint);

        var self = this.onsucces;
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
                self(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 204)
                self();
            else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 400)
                alert(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).error.message);
        };

        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authorizationToken);

        if (typeof this.params !== "undefined")
            for (var pair of this.params.entries()) {
                console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
            }   
        xhr.send(this.params);
  };
}

jukteapi.http = function() {
    return new XHRBuilder('jhjukte','jukte','v1')
}

jukteapi.createShiftlist = function(onsucces, name, start, end) {
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(function(idToken) {
        jukteapi.http().post()
        .path('jeugdhuis/' + jukteKey + '/shiftlists')
        .authorizationToken(idToken)
        .addParam('partyName', name)
        .addParam('start', start + ':00')
        .addParam('end', end + ':00')
        .onsucces(onsucces)
        .send();
    });
}
```

This is the `ShiftlistForm` class.

```
package jukte.form;

import java.util.Date;

public class ShiftlistForm {
    private String partyName;
    private Date start;
    private Date end;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ShiftlistForm() {}

    public ShiftlistForm(String partyName, Date start, Date end){
        this.partyName = partyName;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public String getPartyName() {
        return partyName;
    }

    public Date getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public Date getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setPartyName(String partyName) {
        this.partyName = partyName;
    }

    public void setStart(Date start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public void setEnd(Date end) {
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

The endpoint is called, but the variables in `ShiftlistForm` (start, end, partyName) are `null`. It worked perfectly before I migrated to 2.0 from 1.0. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may want to try setting your `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.